# python daemon signal handling: cannot override default

Tags: python-2.7

I'm writing a python daemon using the daemon module.  I want it to respond to SIGALRM, SIGHUP, SIGUSR1 etc to perform daemon control functions.

I find that the signal handler gets called OK, however the daemon terminates when I expect it to continue running.  How do I get the handler to run without terminating the daemon?

I've tried registering handlers both with signal.signal and with context.signal_map.  The behaviour is the same in both cases.

Proto handler looks like this:

```
def myhandler(signum, frame):
  logger.info("Received Signal: %s at frame: %s" % (signum, frame))
```

Signal registration looks like this

```
context.signal_map = {
  signal.SIGHUP: myhandler,
  signal.SIGUSR1: myhandler,
  signal.SIGUSR2: myhandler,
}
```

Comment: Can you show all your code? The problem should be elsewhere since your mapping seems right.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code works for me:

```
import signal
import daemon
import time


def do_main_program():
    while True:
        with open("/tmp/current_time.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("The time is now " + time.ctime())
        time.sleep(5)


def reload_program_config(signum, frame):
    with open("/tmp/reload.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("The time is now " + time.ctime())
    return None


def run():
    context = daemon.DaemonContext()
    context.signal_map = {
        signal.SIGHUP: 'terminate',
        signal.SIGUSR1: reload_program_config,
    }
    with context:
        do_main_program()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```